# How to know how many mysql queries a php script has done?

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to know how many mysql queries has been launched in a php script ? and how long those queries were ?

thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can make a handler function for your MySQL queries, like:

```
$mysql_queries_count = 0;
$mysql_queries_time = 0;

function _mysql_query($query) {
    global $mysql_queries_count, $mysql_queries_time;

    $start = microtime(true);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $mysql_queries_time += microtime(true) - $start;
    $mysql_queries_count++;

    return $result;
}
```

Doing so, you'll have to replace all `mysql_query(` in your code with `_mysql_query(`, which is easily doable in most text editors.

Comment: though its a pain in the .. well ihave like 500 files now :s . guess it would be better than asking every client to install some packages ...